# VScode - cannot get back to normal shift-arrow selection

Tags: visual-studio-code, selection

For some reason, I cannot get back to what I consider 'normal' shift-arrow selection - meaning what it does in most every text editor when you go to a line and shift arrow down, for instance how it works in this editor here: go to the middle of a line, hit shift and down, and you should get a selection to the end of the line you were on to the middle of the next line where your cursor is now, as a single unbroken block of selection. VScode now always goes into a multi-cursor mode and wants to always do column selection. I do want column selection sometimes, and i have mapped numpad-5 to turn it on and off, and this worked perfectly until yesterday. I have played with all the multi line mode settings and nothing seems to make a difference. Did a recent update change anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Settings, uncheck the `editor.columnSelection` option:

> Editor: Column Selection
> Enable that the selection with the mouse and keys is doing column selection.